# AngularJS routing trouble

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, angularjs-routing

The noobest question ever. 
Here is my code: 
App.coffee:

```
window.app = angular.module "my_super_app", [
  'router'
  'ng-rails-csrf'
]
```

router.coffee:

```
angular.module "router", ['ngRoute']
  .config ($routeProvider) ->
    $routeProvider
      .when '/', {
        controller: "MainCtrl"
      }
  .controller 'MainCtrl', () ->
    console.log "test"
```

Whyyyyyy it doesn't work?? Crying and banging my head on table...
P.S. I added controller into router intentionally.

Answer (score 1):

I got it. It needs ng-view in the layout and `template` or `templateUrl` in the `when` section.